# ServiceNow API - Get required/mandatory fields and data

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

We are looking for a ServiceNow API to get all required/mandatory fields and its data, that a user has to provided before creating a new incident.

Refer to this image:

[image]

Example:

- required/mandatory fields --> [Category, Subcategory, Impact, Urgency, etc ...]
- Data of fields:

  Urgency --> [1: Critical, 2 - High, etc …]

  Category --> [Security, Repair, Remove, ….]

Comment: I found a way to get data of fields under the incident. However, I don't know how to know a field is required or not through an API.

Comment: + https://servertest.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_choice?sysparm_query=name=incident^element=category

+ https://servertest.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_choice?sysparm_query=name=incident^element=subcategory

+ https://servertest.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_choice?sysparm_query=name=incident^element=impact

+ https://servertest.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_choice?sysparm_query=name=incident^element=urgency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this information is stored in the dictionary (right click field label -> dictionary). So you could a request to table sys_dictionary (where table=incident AND mandatory=true) and get the fields from there.

But there are many ways (data policies, business rules, dictionary) and evaluations in servicenow, which will be hard to obtain via REST.

I would advise you to just make a list of fields you want from an incident and make this configurable.

Comment: Do you mean querying the sys_dictionary table "might" let us obtain the information, but the mandatory fields info could also be somewhere hard to reach via REST as well?

Comment: If you want a field to be mandatory you can set it in dictionary, this way it is easy to obtain the info via REST. But you can also set mandatory in a data policy (if user==admin; makeFieldMandatory()), which is hard to obtain via REST (only of you query all data policies and evaluate them in your code)