# " Mandatory fields missing" error while using ServiceNow API

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am using ServiceNow API to create a Catalog request.

URL:

```
https://<ServiceNow>/api/sn_sc/servicecatalog/items/6e2cc01d4f51ce08d4fb2b8ca310c7a6/order_now
```

BODY:

```
{
    "sysparm_quantity":"1",
    "variables":  {
        "requestor":"6e2cc01d4f51ce08d4fb2b8ca310c7a6",
        "Requested For":"6e2cc01d4f51ce08d4fb2b8ca310c7a6",
        "Group Name":"01304c6ddbef9f0827673672399619c4",
        "Group Domain":"FG",
        "Rationale for Approver Only (this will not be viewed by fulfillment team)":"testing"
    }
}
```

I got this error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "detail": "",
        "message": "Mandatory Variables are required"
    },
    "status": "failure"
}
```

How can I know what are the mandatory fields?

Comment: Official Documentation - https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=london&id=SCatAPIOrderNowPOST

Comment: Not a helpful comment. Only sentence in documentation about mandatory fields: "If there are mandatory variables defined for the item, they must be passed to the endpoint." which doesn't answer his question at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServiceNow API - Get required/mandatory fields and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612263/servicenow-api-get-required-mandatory-fields-and-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this ID will be used to get the mandatory variables.
`https://<ServiceNow>/api/sn_sc/servicecatalog/items/<Item_ID>/variables`

However, I don't find it on the service now official documentation.

It should be a scripted API.

Answer (score 0):

Check the elements tab in your browser (F12 for Chrome) while you have the form opened and search for "variable_tab" there you will see all expected variables. You can figure out how the mandatory ones are calle by looking at the form.